# How to determine when view position has changed

Tags: android, view, position

Is there a way to get notification (e.g. through an interface callback) when a View has moved with respect to the screen coordinates?

One could put a wrapper on onLayout(), but I don't think that will catch scrolling or translate movements where the onLayout() isn't called for the view.